# How to use .contains(nodeOrNodes) API when the contained react element has an arrow function event handler?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

For below example, [.contains(nodeOrNodes) => Boolean](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/contains.html) API works fine.

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Comp = ({ onChange }) => (
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" onChange={onChange} />
  </form>
);

export default Comp;
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Comp from '.';

describe('Comp', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    const noop = () => null;
    const wrapper = shallow(<Comp onChange={noop} />);
    expect(
      wrapper.contains(
        <form>
          <input type="text" placeholder="username" onChange={noop} />
        </form>,
      ),
    ).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Unit test results:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/46133847/02/index.test.tsx
  Comp
    ✓ should render (13ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.tsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.754s, estimated 24s
```

But, if I change the `onChange` event handler using the arrow function:

`index.ts`:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Comp = ({ onChange }) => (
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" onChange={(e) => onChange(e)} />
  </form>
);

export default Comp;
```

The unit test will fail.

```sh
 FAIL  src/stackoverflow/46133847/02/index.test.tsx
  Comp
    ✕ should render (18ms)

  ● Comp › should render

    expect(received).toBeTruthy()

    Received: false

      13 |         </form>,
      14 |       ),
    > 15 |     ).toBeTruthy();
         |       ^
      16 |   });
      17 | });
      18 | 

      at Object.it (src/stackoverflow/46133847/02/index.test.tsx:15:7)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.689s, estimated 25s
```

I think the test failed because the arrow function created a new function reference. This new function has a different reference with `noop` function passed into `Comp`.

But what I want is, is there any way like `expect.any(Function)` of `jestjs`, just to assert whether or not the `wrapper` contains any function of `onChange` event handler?

Package versions:

```
"enzyme": "^3.10.0",
"jest": "^24.9.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I do **not** think using .contains(nodeOrNodes) is good way for this situation.

My personal suggestion is followed by below:

```
 let inputComponent = wrapper.find("input[placeholder]='username'");
 expect(inputComponent.length).toBe(1); // This tests your component is exists rather than contains)
 expect(inputComponent.props().onChange).toEqual(noop); //This tests onChange function  is equal your mock function
```

Please vote it, if it works for you